# Removing a page with multiple views without memory leaks in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I got a small app that can contains about 50 views in the same page. Imagine a page with a listview that contains 50 items, each item got it's view.

So I want to remove all that without doing memory leaks, question is, what is the most efficient way to do that?

From what I see I can't just delete the top view, I need to save all those views in a variable and call remove() on everyone one of them, but that seems terribly inefficient.

Also, Would it be wrong to say that if a view has no event binded with listento, it will be garbage collected even if I do not call explicitly remove() on it if I remove the DOM element?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `remove` function of a View is simply:

```
remove: function() {
  this.$el.remove();
  this.stopListening();
  return this;
}
```

So if there aren't any listeners, removing the DOM element is equivalent.